# Set focus to UITextField in tableCell

Tags: ios, events, uitableview, uitextfield

I am creating a table view with `UITextField`s dynamically.

```
l_textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:TextFieldFrame];
l_textField.tag = cellRow;

l_textField.delegate = self;
l_textField.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
l_textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[l_textField setEnabled:YES];

[cell.contentView addSubview:l_textField];
```

And now I want to set focus on this text field when user touch cell. I write this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    UITextField* field = (UITextField *) [tblView viewWithTag: newIndexPath.row];
    [field resignFirstResponder];
}
```

But this doesn't work

Answer (score 60, accepted):

change `[field resignFirstResponder];` with `[field becomeFirstResponder];`

`resignFirstResponder` is used to remove keyboard (focus) from text field

Comment: Nothing happend, I think it like that becouse I set tblView.allowsSelection = NO; And this event doesn't happend. But IF I Set tblView.allowsSelection = YES; It select cell only =(

Comment: I tried to implement such approach however this does not work usually.
Trying to assign the UITextField to [textField becomeFirstResponder] must set the selection enabled or set to YES/true.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue here, even using correctly the `[field becomeFirstResponder];`.

I also used tags to get the objects I have inside the cell. Your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` should look like this to get the right cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    currentRow = indexPath.row;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITextField *indexField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    [indexField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

It worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Swift 3

```
myTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

> My Code. Take index path of current cell. And get cell of next indexpath.row. And called 
>   ** cell1.txtFindings.becomeFirstResponder() **

```
  if  let textFieldIndexPath = specsListView.indexPath(for: cell){
        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: textFieldIndexPath.row + 1, section: 0)

        if let cell1: SpecsTableViewCell = specsListView.cellForRow(at: newIndexPath) as? SpecsTableViewCell{
            cell1.txtFindings.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
}
```